# Place method for FigureCanvasTkAgg in tkinter window?

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, geometry

I am new to tkinter, and I want to place a graph in a TkAgg canvas in a specific position on my tkinter window.
I have setup all of my widgets using the `place()` method, which works best for my cause. I now have a large white space left, where the canvas with the graph should go. Is there any way to get the canvas to that exact spot with the available methods `grid()` and `pack()` or is there anything close to the `place()` method for FigureCanvasTkAgg?

A snipped of my code

```
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
graph = nx.Graph()
...

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.configure(bg="white")
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack()
...
```

what i wish would work is

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=390, y=190, anchor='w')
```

but it ignores `place()` and just packs it in the top left of the window.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new frame and place it however you want.

Then add the canvas to that frame using `pack()`.

```
frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.place(...)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=frm)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. You made my day in isolation.

Comment: Glad I could help :)